# IntelliSense suggests Brushes for Brush, how?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When writing `graphics.FillEllipse(`, we can see the first parameter to that method is an instance of the `Brush` class. However, IntelliSense immediately suggests to use `Brushes`, a class containing many predefined `Brush` instances.

[image]

How does it do this? Is this something I can make Visual Studio do with my own classes as well?

Comment: For the record, this also happens with VS2015 (and potentially more), not just in 2017.

Comment: There is no code you could write where "Brush" is valid as the first argument.  It is an abstract class.  You'd have to create a concrete brush with, say, `new SolidBrush(...)`.  Or use pre-defined brushes, you know, from the Brushes class.  Behold the "intelli" in IntelliSense.  Please don't use CreateGraphics(), it is not intelli.

Comment: I understand I couldn't just pass in an instance of a `Brush`, but how does VS know it needs to suggest the `Brushes` class? If the class were called `MyBrushCollection`, would it still work?